# EXCEL- way to show line between cells when matched

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to visually represent lookups to show match relations? i.e. make it draw a line from
(A3 to C5, C6, C8 ) if there is a lookup match between A3 and C5, C6, C8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to automatically draw lines in Excel, but this needs
to be programmed in VBA.

The VBA verb to use will be
[Shapes.AddLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addline).

Writing a VBA trigger that will draw these lines is not simple
and requires acquiring good knowledge of VBA.

Example code from the article :

```
Set myDocument = Worksheets(1) 
With myDocument.Shapes.AddLine(10, 10, 250, 250).Line 
 .DashStyle = msoLineDashDotDot 
 .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 0, 128) 
End With
```

Comment: thanks the lines part is the easy part. looked it up, will need to work out the cell().top & cell().left via pointers to get the xy coordinates on screen refresh. but it helps.